# Mathematical question about currencies

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics, ratio

I've tried to get an answer for this question elsewhere but with no luck, so I would appreciate a mathematical analysis of it.

Assume $0\%$ commission. Consider three currencies, let's say the Zong, the Yabba and the Xoxo. The Zong is trading against the Yabba at say z:y, the Yabba against the Xoxo at y:x and Xoxo against the Zong at x:z.

Then surely:

$$\dfrac{z}{x}\times\dfrac{y}{z}\times\dfrac{x}{y}=1$$

, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Is the commission keeping this stable?

Comment: Yong or Yabba? (in the second paragraph, second line...) just in case...

Comment: @iadvd - thanks, the Yabba

Comment: I understand that you mean for z units of Zong you get x units of Xoxo... but why do you divide them and multiply all together in the final formula? If I remember clearly (hope not to be wrong) if changes in the commissions or buy/sell prices do not happen while trading (for instance in intraday operations), then there is no change in the benefit or lose if you do the complete circle and the prices of selling and buying are the same ones (buy Yabba buy Xoxo, then buy Zong again), but in the real world the changes are happening every microseconds so there is always benefit or lose.

Comment: The Zong is trading against the Yabba at say z:y, which means with $1$ Zong you can buy $\frac{y}{z}$ Yabba.  The Yabba against to Xoxo at y:x, which means with $1$ Yabba you can buy $\frac{x}{y}$ Xoxo which means with $1$ Zong you can buy $\frac{x}{y} \times \frac{y}{z}=\frac{x}{z}$ Xoxo, this confirms/validates your third condition, Xoxo against to Zong at x:z, which means with $1$ Xoxo you can buy $\frac{z}{x}$ Zong and lastly with $1$ Zong you can buy $1$ Zong.

Comment: @Vikram; which is true if the ratios are behaving themselves, but say there is a massive trade from Zong to Yabba, how do z:x and y:x respond?

Comment: @iadvd; because if you take a snapshot of the current rates, (ignore commission, fees, etc. - this is an abstract Q) the actual answer is rarely exactly 1, so there is some leeway.

Comment: that is Economics question, better ask at http://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Vikram; I asked CNBC, and they didn 't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're assuming a completely fair currency market, then it makes perfect sense: essentially what your equation is telling you is the rate at which the Xoxo is trading against itself. That is, if you take $x$ Xoxo's, you can trade it in for $z$ Zongs which you can then turn in for $y$ Yabbas which you can then turn in for $x$ Xoxo's.  So your overall rate becomes, $x:x$ Xoxo's, which simplifies to $1.$

In the real world, however, these rates aren't going to be totally fair, so you would have to use 3 totally independent ratios, e.g., $z_1:y_1$ Zongs to Yabbas, $y_2:x_1$ Yabbas to Xoxo's, and $x_2:z_2$ Xoxo's to Zongs. And so then your rate of Xoxo's to Xoxo's by trading Xoxo's to Zongs to Yabbas to Xoxo's would become:
$$\frac{z_2}{x_2}\cdot\frac{y_1}{z_1}\cdot\frac{x_1}{y_2}$$
Which may be greater than, less than, or equal to $1$.

Comment: yes true, but these ratios (one would have thought) would equalize fairly rapidly. If 1z bought 2y bought 3x which bought 1.1z you've got money for nothing.

Comment: Exactly. Some people make money off of trading currencies, somewhat like stocks.  Others lose it.  Of course, these rates are constantly changing, so it's not like it's some magic formula to get money for free.

Comment: well yes it is - if you work out the ratios and (apply commission) you **CAN** guarantee a profit.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No you can't. Mainly because of market fluctuation, market reaction and commissions. If you are good at predicting the changes then you can make money but you won't be able to guarantee it. In some cases you might also have issues with liquidity. Liquidity and market reaction might actually become an issue when you are trying to make any interesting amount of money. Since the differences in costs will be small you will need to shift a pretty large amount of money to make any.